# Não consigo validar formulário em Cake PHP 3

Tags: cakephp

Olá, sou novo em CakePHP 3 e estou tendo problemas na validação do meu form login.ctp, erro: undefined variable users in login.ctp.

Agradeceria se alguém pudesse me ajudar a validar;

**login.ctp**:

```
<br>
<div class="index large-4 medium-5  large-offset-4 medium-offset-4 columns">
    <div class="panel">
        <h2 class="text-center">Login</h2>
        <?= $this->Form->create($user); ?>

             <?php

            echo $this->Form->input('email');
            echo $this->Form->input('password');
                ?>

            <?= $this->Form->submit('Login', array('class' => 'button')); ?>

        <?= $this->Form->end(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

login function em **UsersController.php**:

```
public function login()
    {           
        if($this->request->is('post'))
        {
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();

            if($user)
            {
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'comentario']);
            }

            // Erro no Login

            $this->Flash->error('Erro de autenticação');
        }



    }
```

Comment: Essa indicação "<?=", será que você poderia substituir por "<?php" ?? Posso estar sendo simplista, mas seria minha sugestão.

Answer (score 0):

Na sua View, coloque essa validação no começo do código. Essa variavel, vai vir do controller quando o login for inválido e a validação irá preencher os campos com a variavel $user.

```
<?php if (empty($user)) {
    $user = 'User';
} ?>
<div class="index large-4 medium-5 large-offset-4 medium-offset-4 columns">
    <div class="panel">
        <h2 class="text-center">Login</h2>
        <?= $this->Form->create($user); ?>

            <?php
                echo $this->Form->input('email');
                echo $this->Form->input('password');
            ?>

            <?= $this->Form->submit('Login', array('class' => 'button')); ?>

        <?= $this->Form->end(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```